# Rails ActiveRecord, checking for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let `c` be anything, (or nil) is:

```
if !c.nil?
  true
else
  false
end
```

The same as

```
if c
  true
else
  false
end
```

Also, is:

```
Model.where(:name => params[:foo])
```

The same as:

```
Model.where('name = ?', params[:foo])
```

Coming from a Java background, does the hash method of passing to a #where() offers escaping? Is there an advantage of using one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, yes these are identical. Also, yes, the hash format does offer escaping. It actually will do more than that depending on if `params[:foo]` is a list it will change between an `=` and an `in` (possibly more things too).

In the future, you can easily see what SQL the AREL statement generates by using the `to_sql` method.

`Model.where(:name => params[:foo]).to_sql`

Generally, the convention is to use the hash syntax when it is sufficient. It is usually easier to read, especially when you have queries that involve multiple models. For example:

`Model.joins(:other_model).where(:name => params[:foo], :other_model => {:attr => params[:bar]})`

Comment: Thanks. I've always used `if !c.nil?` because it is more explicit, and I find this is more difficult to read.